# This Riley Riddle must be in proper order

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My prefix is when you do something bad.
>
> Somewhere in the middle you can see a choice between a yes and a no.
>
> And lastly I have a financial suffix.
>
> I also like keeping things in order!

**What am I?**

Hint:

> The prefix *sounds like* - but not the same spelling.

Comment: Can this really count as a Riley riddle without an infix? (I make no comment on whether being a Riley riddle is a good thing or not -- there have been an awful lot of them lately -- but if you're going to call it one then it should probably actually be one...)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I hereby declare that the infix, while highly encouraged, is optional for Riley riddle status.

Comment: OMG the author of these kind of riddles commented :)

Comment: @Riley lmao you got a fan

Comment: @Riley Ah, well, but ["the author is dead"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_the_Author) and I'm not sure you get to decide what counts as a Riley riddle merely because you are Riley :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I added an infix after realizing I needed to add it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps:

> **Syntax**

*My prefix is when you do something bad.*

> Syn sounds like 'sin'

*Somewhere in the middle you can see a choice between a yes and a no.*

> Y\N is a common abbreviation of Yes\No

*And lastly I have a financial suffix.*

> Tax is a financial term

*...keeping things in order/proper order*

> Syntax is the proper arrangement of words in a sentence.

Comment: yes thats the correct  answer

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer.

> Deathrate

My prefix is something bad

> Death is bad.

And lastly I have a financial suffix

> Rate is a common term used in finance.

I also like keeping things in order

> Deathrate helps to keep the population of country in order as overpopulation is bad.

Comment: "My infix keeps me down" rot13(rng)  :)

Comment: Nice answer but it is not the answer I was looking for

Comment: I thought "qrngu engr" was two words.

Comment: For the benefit of any further commenters (or would-be editors), this post quotes the original wording of the riddle (see Edit History) before the text was altered/improved by the OP in later edits :)